# R - how do I run each function in a list of functions with parameters given by a vector

Tags: r, lambda, functional-programming, anonymous-function

Suppose I have a list of functions and a vector of parameter values:

```
functions <- list(a = function(x) x *2, b = function(x) x*3, c = function(x) x * 4)
paramVector <- c(2, 2, 1)
```

Now I want the following functionality of calling each function with the corresponding parameter and collating the result into a vector:

```
result <- c()
for (idx in 1:length(functions)) {
    result[idx] <- functions[[idx]](paramVector[idx])
}
result
```

Is there a way to do this without the for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To iterate over the `functions` and `paramVector` objects at the same time, use Map. For example

```
Map(function(f,p) f(p), functions, paramVector)
```

Note that `Map()` always returns a list. You can also use `mapply()` which will attempt to simplify to a vector

```
mapply(function(f,p) f(p), functions, paramVector)
```

Comment: `mapply` might be more appropriate given they want the result as a vector.